# How to check facebook profile url exists on facebook or not in aspnet mvc 4 c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have used this code but it return `200 status code` in case of invalid facebook url

I have validate 4 social media URL that is `twitter` ,`facebook`, `linkedin` , `xing`

```
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
req.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
HttpWebResponse res = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
if (res.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK || res.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Found)
    return true;
else
    return false;
```

Comment: I guess they have custom pages for http errors that is why it returns 200 status code

Comment: Yes sir you are absolutely right.Is there is any way to validtae social media url for (facebook,twitter,linkedin,xing)

Comment: How graph api can be used to validate facebook profile url of any users?

Comment: Why not read the content of the page to see if it's a valid one?

Comment: Yes correctly suggested by @kevintjuh93. you can analyze the custom error page and read specific content to determine if page is valid or not

Comment: How to use Graph API to validate Facebook profile Url of all users while SignUp in my Application.